# DRF - using view classes for custom URL design?

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I would like to realise the following URL design (based on githubs' REST api) for a `User` model in django rest framework:

```
# get authenticated user (the currently logged in user):
#
#   GET user/
#
# update authenticated user:
#
#   PATCH user/
#
# get single user (will only return instructors)
#
# GET user/:username
#
# get all users (will only return instructors)
#
# GET users/
```

Given a `User` model I have the following standard serializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = models.MyUser
        fields = '__all__'
```

I can implement the url routes using function based views for each URL, but DRF offers many class-based views and routers and I was wondering if there was a more concise way of implementing it?

Answer (score 1):

I realise this is a little late but incase anyone else finds this:

**viewset.py:**

```
class UserViewSet(RetrieveModelMixin, UpdateModelMixin, GenericViewSet):
    queryset = None
    serializer_class = serializers.UserSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user
```

This isn't a full example for the one above but is a good example. Here `get_object` doesn't rely on a queryset, but can still provide an object without a `pk`.

**urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    # GET:  /user/ [Retrieve]
    # PUT:  /user/ [Update]
    url(
        r'^user/$',
        UserViewSet.as_view({'get': 'retrieve', 'put': 'update'}),
        name='user'
    ),
]
```

Here, instead of relying on the `drf` router to provide the urls (which automatically include a `pk` object), the routes are defined in the standard Django format. This allows for the removal of a detail `pk` (or the addition of an optional one etc).

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can make a view subclass generics.GenericAPIView, and add mixins for CURD like the following codes:

#### urls.py

```
url(r'^/user/(?P<pk>\d+)/detail/$', UserDetailView.as_view(), name='user_detail'),
url(r'^/user/(?P<pk>\d+)/update/$', UserDetailView.as_view(), name='user_update'),
url(r'^/user/list/$', UserListView.as_view(), name='user_list'),
```

#### views.py

```
from rest_framework import mixins
from rest_framework import generics

class UserListView(mixins.ListModelMixin,
                   generics.GenericAPIView):
    queryset = MyUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)

class UserDetailView(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                     mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                     mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
                     generics.GenericAPIView):
    queryset = MyUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def patch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.partial_update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

If you need more control on the logic, you can:

1. [User List]: override the `get_queryset` in `UserListView`, and supply your logic to filter users and return the queryset.
2. [Get user detail]: same as above, but override `get_queryset` in `UserDetailView`
3. [Patch user]: override `partial_update` in `UserDetailView` to supply your logic for updating.

In a word, mixins is the good place for you to start to create more generic class-based views on DRF.

Comment: Hmm, thanks but the key difference here is the URLs. You are expecting a PK to be passed in the url (and I think the mixins in the UserDetailView expect this?). The url I want has no PK - it returns details for the logged in user.